# Face Recognition and tracking with raspberry pi3

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

Im working on face tracking robot with raspberry pi 3 project. I have done with face detection part with opencv on raspberry pi . i need help with the motor control

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

We can adjust motor control with the recognized real time face.During recognition divide frames of the camera into number of section and simply label it and according to the position of detected face in the labeled section change the motor control code.
for ex.

```
while(True):
    ret, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    reg=width/4

    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        centre_x = x + w/2
        centre_y = y + w/2
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        if faces is not None:
            if centre_x<((width-reg)/2):
                print('left')
                leftturn()
            elif centre_x>((width+reg)/2):
                print('right')
                rightturn()
            else:

                print('center')
                forward()
        else:
            stop()
```

frames are divided into 4 sections (reg=width/4)
Hope, this may help